# understanding in/out exchange pattern behaviour in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

**In camel, is it correct to say that not all `ENDPOINT`s support `INOUT` `ExchangePattern` ?**
If yes, then where which part of documentation tells which endpoint support which `ExchangePattern` or this is a implicit kind knowledge.

Its upto `ENDPOINT` to give support to `INOUT`.

Below is code example based on which i came to conclusion.

---

I was playing with camel example-jms-file and i modify it to

queue1 --> queue2 ---> file://test ---> file://test1

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {                         

            from("test-jms:queue:test.queue1")
            .process(sleep(1))
            .to("test-jms:queue:test.queue2");

            from("test-jms:queue:test.queue2")
            .process(sleep(2))
            .to("file://test");

            from("file://test")
            .process(sleep(3))
            .to("file://test1");
        }

        private Processor sleep(final int sleepId) {
            return new Processor() {                    
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {                       
                    System.out.println("Going for sleep sleepid=" + sleepId + ",  thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Thread.sleep(5000l);                        
                    System.out.println("Done sleep sleepid=" + sleepId + ",  thread=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

Then i send a msg to queue using below code:

```
        Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
        exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
        exchange.getIn().setBody("Test Message: 1");
  System.out.println("sending msg to queue1");
       Exchange send = template.send("test-jms:queue:test.queue1",exchange);
  // If queue and file endpoint support INOUT then below line should get printed at last.
  System.out.println("received response");
```

Executing above give following response:

```
sending msg to queue1  

Going for sleep sleepid=1,  thread=Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[test.queue1]

Done sleep sleepid=1,  thread=Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[test.queue1]

Going for sleep sleepid=2,  thread=Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[test.queue2]

Done sleep sleepid=2,  thread=Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[test.queue2]

received response   ## this getting printed here meaning that the file endpoint do not respect the INOUT exchangepattern.

Going for sleep sleepid=3,  thread=Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - file://test    

Done sleep sleepid=3,  thread=Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - file://test
```

If we observe the execution output we will see that *received response* gets printed before the completion of route starting with `FILE` `ENDPOINT`.

This shows that the file endpoint did not understood that the exchange is a INOUT exchange

---

pictorial representation:(click image to enlarge)

### [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Not all camel endpoints support INOUT. The JMS endpoint supports it but the file endpoint does not.

Unfortunately this is indeed not well documented.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you expect from `INOUT` of a component.

In you example

```
.to("file://test");
```

writes a file and finishes. It does not wait (and should not wait) for another process/client to pick up a file and possibly to do something with it (delete it?).

If you are looking for communication between 2 routes, check [direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) or [seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) components

Comment: INOUT is equal to request-reply... in mentioned example we can see two behavior. [1] when message is getting routed btw queue1 and queue2 "recevied msg" wasnt got printed. [2] but when msg got routed between queue1 and file  "recevied msg" got printed... http://camel.apache.org/async.html#Async-SynchronousRequestReply